# MomentJs/Angular Date filter not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I've my date format as '2017-05-16T13:22:01.207Z' and trying to convert to '05/16/17 08:22 AM'. I've tried the following and none of them worked for me in IE, works fine in chrome. Any ideas what is the reason. Did anyone ever face this situation.

```
Date = '2017-05-16T13:22:01.207Z';

MomentJs Solution:

$moment(Date).format('MM-DD-YY HH:mm A').replace(/-/g,"/")

AngularJs Date Filter:

{{Date | date: 'short'}}
```

Expected Result: I'm seeing this in chrome, but not in IE

```
 05-16-17 13:22 PM
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, can you provide a fiddle or a snippet? Which is the IE version that gives you problems? Native angularjs date filter works for me, no need to use neither moment nor replace in this case. (I'm not the downvoter btw)

Comment: I just figured out the issue, the issue is in the template where it applies this filter based on an ng-if, this particular filter is never being applied on IE because of the condition in the ng-if. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 1):

Hehe, the replace might be the funniest way I've seen someone handling the `format()` function, which already formats a date as one wishes.

Use

```js
var date = '2017-05-16T13:22:01.207Z';
alert(moment(date).format('MM/DD/YY HH:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

**Also note!!!**

`Date` is already defined in js (it's the global Date object); so you'd be better off using some different name for your variable - like the similar sounding `date`; but with a lowercased D/d. (This might be where your error comes from)

Comment: You are right, I didn't pay much attention to that formatting stuff. I tried it in some plunkr which didn't work, may be some typo that I didn't realize.